# LSTM for vector to character sequence translation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm looking to build a sequence-to-sequence model that takes in a 2048-long vector of 1s and 0s (ex. [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,...,1] ) as my input and translating it to my known output of (a variable length) 1-20 long characters (ex. GBNMIRN, ILCEQZG, or FPSRABBRF).

My goal is to create a model that can take in a new 2048-long vector of 1s and 0s and predict what the output sequence will look like.

I've looked at some github repositories like [this](https://github.com/llSourcell/seq2seq_model_live/blob/master/2-seq2seq-advanced.ipynb%20) and [this](https://github.com/hans/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/tf/TF%20tutorial.ipynb).

but I'm not sure how to implement it with my problem. Are there any projects that have done something similar to this/how could I implement this with the seq2seq models or LSTMs currently out there? (python implementations)

I am using the keras library in python.

Comment: What have you tried in which language?

Comment: How are you encoding/normalizing your input strings?

Comment: Would it be possible to convert my binary vector to ascii and then normalize the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is strange as it is an binary-code. I don't know whether the model will work well.

First of all, you need to add start and end marks for your input and output which indicates the boundaries. Then design regional module of each time step, including how to use hidden state. You could try simple GRU/LSTM networks as following.

[image]

For details, you could try **Encoder**

[image]

and **Decoder**

[image]

In addition, you could take a look at **Attention mechanism** in paper [Neural Machine Translation by Jointly Learning to Align and Translate](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf). And the structure is as following.

[image]

For details

[image]

Though you are using Keras, I think it will be helpful to read PyTorch codes as it is straightforward and easy to understand. The tutorial given in [PyTorch tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html)